# set value range for java class attribute

Tags: java

Is it possible to set a value range for a java class attribute inside the constructor?

I know that you can do somethink like that inside set-methods with an if statement, but that's not what I want to do.

Thanks in advance.

Example class "Items":

```
public class Items {
public int id;
public String from;
public String to;

public Items(int id, String from, String to) {
    this.id=id;
    this.from=from;
    this.to=to;
}
```

value range in setter:

```
public void setId(int id){
    if(id>10 && id<100){
        this.id=id;
    }
}
```

Can you do something similar in the consructor? (For int und string)

Comment: Please give a more detailed explanation of what you want to do. Currently it is not clear.

Comment: If you know how to do something similar in a setter (set-method), add this code to the question. This shows some effort and gives a better understanding on what you want and why something else is not working out for you.

Comment: Well if you can do that in setter method so you can invoke this setter inside constructor. Instead of this.id=id use setId(id)

Comment: If I might be a little pedantic, that is not a value range in the set method, that is a check that a value is in a range

Comment: But if I do it like that the object would exist with maybe empty variables. I don't want the object to exist if the variables don't have the right values.

Comment: You cannot do that in constructor then. Because if you invoke it then object will be created. You have to construct your own method for creation which will check this range and return null or exception if it not fulfill your range condition. Example below in Lino's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're maybe better of making your class immutable with a private constructor and then use a `static` factory method:

```
public final class Items {
    public final int id;
    public final String from;
    public final String to;

    private Items(int id, String from, String to) {
        this.id=id;
        this.from=from;
        this.to=to;
    }

    public static Items create(int id, String from, String to) {
        // check that id is in a valid range
        if(id <= 10 || id >= 100){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Id must be between 10 and 100");
        }

        // here you can check "from" and "to" too and check that they are valid

        // if no exception has been thrown 
        // then we can safely say that the arguments are valid
        return new Items(id, from, to);
    }
}
```

The advantage of this approach is:

- no field of `Items` will ever change because you've made every field as well as the class `final` this will make the class `Items` directly safe to use by multiple threads (Iff the fields are also immutable).
- No object is constructed if you pass invalid arguments. Generally throwing exceptions in a constructor is discouraged. As the object is in a creation phase and then gets thrown away

You see this approach in many classes in the jdk, and aswell in many libraries.

Comment: I think that will exactly do what I want! :)